# Не отправляется форма ajax php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть форма:

```
            <form form-name="callback" id='callback' class="js-form">
            
                <div class="form-group">
                <input field-name="phone" name="phone" type="text" class="phone form-control" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__">
                <small class="form-text text-muted">Укажите ваш номер телефона и мы свяжемся с вами в ближайшее время.</small>
                </div>
                
                <button class="submit btn btn-warning">Перезвоните мне!</button>
            </form>
```

js обработчик:

```
    self.Send = function()
    {
        if ( typeof self.GetExport().phone !== 'undefined' )
        {
            var obj = JSON.stringify( self.GetExport() );
            
            console.log( obj );
            
            $.post( 'no', obj )
            .done( function( data )
            {
                console.log( data );
                
                self.Clear();
                modals.HideAll(); // скрыть все модальные окна
                modals.Open( 'form-success' ); // показать modal success
            } );
        }
        else
        {
            alert( 'Номер телефона не может быть пустым!' );
        }
    };
```

Не могу написать php код для принятия этих данных и отправки на почту
php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['email'])) {$email = $_POST['email']; if ($email == '') {unset($email);}}
if (isset($_POST['phone'])) {$phone = $_POST['phone']; if ($phone == '') {unset($phone);}}
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {$text = $_POST['name']; if ($text == '') {unset($text);}}
 
$answer=['ok'=>$phone.' = phone'];

if (isset($email) or isset($phone) or isset($text)){
    $to  = "<whisper@***.ru>, " ; 
    $to .= "<***off@mail.ru>"; 

    $subject = "Заявка с сайта!"; 

    $message = ' <b>Имя:'.$name.' </b> </br> <b>Телефон: '.$phone.'</b> </br><i>Почта: '.$email.'</i> </br>';

    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
    $headers .= "From: <admin@***>\r\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ***off@mail.ru\r\n"; 


    $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 

    if ($send == true) {
        $answer =[
            'ok'=>'done'
        ];
    }
    else {
        $answer=[
            'ok'=>'error'
        ];
    }
}
echo json_encode($answer);

?>
```

В консоли в ответ получаю такое:
{"phone":"71515123131","form":"callback","url":"/"}
{"ok":" = phone"}

Как я понял - я неправильно распарсиваю данные в php. Как тут нужно это делать?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
        header('Content-type: application/json');
        $name = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['name']));
        $phone = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['phone']));
        $email = htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['email']));
        $answer = [];
    
        if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($phone)) {
            $to  = "<whisper@***.ru>, " ; 
            $to .= "<***off@mail.ru>"; 
    
            $subject = "Заявка с сайта!"; 
    
            $message = ' <b>Имя:'.$name.' </b> </br> <b>Телефон: '.$phone.'</b> </br><i>Почта: '.$email.'</i> </br>';
    
            $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
            $headers .= "From: <admin@***>\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "Reply-To: ***off@mail.ru\r\n"; 
    
            $send = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    
            if ($send) {
                $answer = [
                    'status' => 'done',
                    'name' => $name,
                    'email' => $email,
                    'phone' => $phone
                ];
    
            } else {
                $answer = ['status' => 'error', 'content' => 'Ошибка при отправке сообщения'];
            }
    
        } else {
            $answer = ['status' => 'error', 'content' => 'Форма заполнена не полностью'];
        }
    
        echo json_encode($answer);
    }
```